# Calculating a simple CRC

Tags: c, crc, ethercat

In the datasheet for the [ET1200](http://download.beckhoff.com/download/Document/EtherCAT/Development_products/EtherCAT_ET1200_Datasheet_all_v1i7.pdf) EtherCAT ASIC (page 94), I am told that I need to calculate a CRC of some of the 16-bit data in its EEPROM. The only description of this CRC is:

> Low byte [of word 7] contains remainder of division of word 0 to word 6 as unsigned number divided by the polynomial \$x^8+x^2+x+1\$ (initial value 0xFF).

For some reason, reading the Wikipedia page on [Calculating a CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC) makes my brain melt. Especially since the example code is written in a special language.

Can someone please just tell me what I need to add to what, and shift where and whatnot? In C preferably.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you watching Ben Easter channel. He explained it so well! Theory:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izG7qT0EpBw Practice:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNkERQlK8j8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like CRC8.

```
/*  
 * crc8.c
 * 
 * Computes a 8-bit CRC 
 * 
 */

#include <stdio.h>


#define GP  0x107   /* x^8 + x^2 + x + 1 */
#define DI  0x07


static unsigned char crc8_table[256];     /* 8-bit table */
static int made_table=0;

static void init_crc8()
     /*
      * Should be called before any other crc function.  
      */
{
  int i,j;
  unsigned char crc;

  if (!made_table) {
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
      crc = i;
      for (j=0; j<8; j++)
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((crc & 0x80) ? DI : 0);
      crc8_table[i] = crc & 0xFF;
      /* printf("table[%d] = %d (0x%X)\n", i, crc, crc); */
    }
    made_table=1;
  }
}


void crc8(unsigned char *crc, unsigned char m)
     /*
      * For a byte array whose accumulated crc value is stored in *crc, computes
      * resultant crc obtained by appending m to the byte array
      */
{
  if (!made_table)
    init_crc8();

  *crc = crc8_table[(*crc) ^ m];
  *crc &= 0xFF;
}
```

Taken from: http://www.rajivchakravorty.com/source-code/uncertainty/multimedia-sim/html/crc8_8c-source.html

http://sbs-forum.org/marcom/dc2/20_crc-8_firmware_implementations.pdf

C implementations without lookup table (especially good for the 8-bit CPU optimised function):

http://websvn.hylands.org/filedetails.php?repname=Projects&path=%2Fcommon%2FCrc8.c&sc=1

Comment: Thanks! Now that I know it has a proper name, suddenly I can find example code for it on Google.

Comment: @joby, glad to see you again! Mind bringing some of the information from those sources over so we are not link rot sensitive?

Comment: @Kortuk Fair point, there you go

Comment: @JobyJaffey, and there you go. Hope you hang around and answer some more questions!

Comment: One problem i have with this code is that the polynomial, GP, isn't used anywhere within the code. So what polynomial is the CRC using to calculate it's CRC table :( DI is used however.

Comment: Do you have an example of how these functions are used and initialised?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the CRC-8/ROHC algorithm. According to the [Catalogue of parametrised CRC algorithms](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat.crc-8-rohc), its parameters are:

```
width=8 poly=0x07 init=0xff refin=true refout=true xorout=0x00 check=0xd0 name="CRC-8/ROHC"
```

Note that [CRC-8](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat.crc-8) uses the same polynomial, but uses an initial value of `0x00`, not `0xFF`. It is also a "non-reflected" algorithm (bits are MSbit first). Its parameters are:

```
width=8 poly=0x07 init=0x00 refin=false refout=false xorout=0x00 check=0xf4 name="CRC-8"
```

These parameters can be used with various tools that can calculate CRCs or generate CRC code, such as [Online CRC calculation](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) or [pycrc, a free CRC source code generator](https://pycrc.org/).